# get unpaid staff id for this month salary sql query for codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Table A (Staffs)

```
id | name | salary    
1  | xxxx | 300    
2  | yyyy | 200    
3  | zzzz | 300
```

Table B (Salary)

```
id | staffId | monthofpay | paydate    
1  | 1       | jan2020    | 2020-01-01    
2  | 2       | jan2020    | 2020-01-01    
3  | 1       | feb2020    | 2020-02-01    
4  | 2       | feb2020    | 2020-02-01    
5  | 3       | feb2020    | 2020-02-01    
6  | 3       | mar2020    | 2020-03-01
```

Table A for Staffs

Table B for Salary

i want to fetch the staff list who not pay for month of March

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, read the guideline and provide us more explanation about your tries and the code you already have implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and here is the [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ENK64wiwD6aJoY3Eyvq2D/0).

```
select
    id
from staff st
where not exists
(
    select
        staffId
    from salary s
    where st.id = s.staffId
    and monthofpay = 'mar2020'
)
```